# ~できやすい and ~しやすい connotation

Tags: meaning, nuances

- しやすい　to effortlessly do something.
- できやすい something is easily made.

Then, how  are フランス料理が作りやすい and フランス料理ができやすい compared?
Would they have a similar connotation?

I understand for the fact that they are different.
So, if anyone can point out a major idea in usage of both, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

できる is a tricky verb because it both means "to form / to be built / to be ready" and "to be able to [suru-verb] / to do [suru-verb] easily".

But when it's followed by やすい, できやすい means "tend to form ～", "tend to be built as ～", "easily turns into ～", etc, because やすい already means "easily / can / has a tendency to ～".

- **フランス料理は作りやすい。**: OK, (as a general fact) French cuisine is easy to prepare. A person who says this must be a very good cook.
- **フランス料理が作りやすい。**: Exhaustive-listing が. (Among other cuisine in the world) It's French cuisine that one is good at.
- **フランス料理はできやすい。**: ("French cuisine easily forms"(?) Makes no sense to me)
- **フランス料理ができやすい。**: Something like "It easily produces / turns into French cuisine". It sounds like you were using a game item which gives 'French cuisine' or something different randomly.
- **フランス料理はできる。**: Contrastive は. A person who said this is good at French cuisine, but implies he's not good at other types of cuisine.
- **フランス料理ができる。**: Neutral-description or exhaustive-listing が, depending on the context. A person who said this is good at French cuisine.