# Why is を used with 作りにくい？

Tags: grammar

Examples I have seen are

> 例文を作りにくいです。

> なぜ大人になると友達を作りにくいのか？

I thought にくい transforms verbs into a イ形容詞.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

にくい can transform both verbs *and verb phrases* into *difficult to ...*.

- 例文を作りにくい = (例文を作る) + にくい : It is difficult to make sample sentences.
- 友達を作りにくい = (友達を作る) + にくい : It is difficult to make friends.

Here **を** is used because 友達 is an object of the predicate 作る, and にくい makes the whole verb phrases into adjectives.

What you had in mind were probably

- 例文は作りにくい = 例文は + (作る + にくい) : Sample sentences are difficult to make.
- 友達は作りにくい = 友達は + (作る + にくい) : Friends are difficult to make.

which are also valid (also が instead of は is possible). Here **は(が)** is used because they are subjects of the sentences.

There is not much difference. The former describes a property of action (making sentences or friends) and the latter a property of sentences or friends in terms of making.

**Additional comment**

Usages of は/を/が above are not totally interchangeable, but it should require another question.

Comment: A particle is defined by the verb．作る is a transitive verb https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B/ all of the examples indicate usage of particle を. Suffix にくい identifies spesific context, this is why particle は usually follows the verb spesific particle, but in this situatton the original particle falls out and only は remains. I don't see how が can be used with 作る, unless it is the potential form: 作れにくい?

Comment: @user1602 が is used with 「verbにくい」「verbづらい」"difficult to~" as well as 「verbやすい」"easy to~", eg 「[字が読みにくい](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%AD%97%E3%81%8C%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8F%E3%81%84%22)」「[字が読みづらい](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%AD%97%E3%81%8C%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%22)」「[フランス料理が作りやすい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30052/9831)」

Comment: @user1602 I added lines. Hopefully they clarify.

Comment: To make the terminology clear: adjective - a word class (part of speech), attributive - syntactical unit (part of sentence). In the example 作りにくい is an attributive to the noun の, which is in turn is a part of complex predicate のだ (copula だ is omitted in this example). Here is a full sentence analysis:

なぜ(adverbial of reason) (私たちは implied subject of the 1st clause) 大人になる (change of state predicate) と (particle connecting two independent clauses) <それは is implied subject of the 2nd clause> 友達を作りにくい (attributive phrase) [の(だ implied copula) stative predicate] か (auxiliary question particle)

Comment: The more I think about it the stronger I feel that が cannot be be used with 作りにくい. In Japanese: 友達が(誰の友達?)作りにくい(何を作りにくい?) This is 珍紛漢紛 . The English idiom: "to make friends" 友達を作る. 友達が作る means "friends make (something)". What do they make?

Comment: 友達が作りにくい is as grammatical as 自然が美しい.  作りにくい  works just as an adjective.  I mean 'to establish friendship with others' by 'to make friends.'　If 'Friends are difficult to make' sounds strange, then you have to  translate it in other ways, but it is just another matter. The point is that 友達が作りにくい describes  a general statement about 'friends', and saying they are hard to get.

Comment: @user1602 I think I see your concerns. Comparing the versions with が/は/を, some do sound like modifying nouns than others. But to me, it seems to involve too many factors and you need to consider a lot more examples. So I reverted your edits and left it as it was. As far as the original question is concerned, it should give a decent answer.

Comment: Works the same in English. 1: Friends are hard to make. 2: It is hard to make friends. In 1) "friends" is a subject, in 2) "friends" is an object.

Comment: I was thinking about this for a while and realized that all complex verbs have a duality in terms of particle usage. 作る requires を as a transitive verb, and 難い requires が as the stative predicate. So both を and が are grammatically correct with 作りにくい.